# How to set timeout for gloo ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, gloo

I am replacing nginx ingress with gloo ingress controller in kubernetes cluster and want to set timeout for response.There is an annotation for this in nginx.

> **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "60"**

Is there anything similar this in gloo-ingress-controller or else do I have to use virtualservice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only annotation that you are supposed to use with Gloo is `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gloo` which is the standard way to mark an Ingress object as handled by a specific Ingress controller. This requirement will go away if you add the ability for Gloo to be the default Ingress controller for your cluster. Also, according to the [documentation](https://docs.solo.io/gloo/1.2.0/gloo_integrations/ingress/):

> If you need more advanced routing capabilities, we encourage you to
> use Gloo VirtualServices by installing as glooctl install gateway.
>
> Gloo Gateway uses Kubernetes Custom Resources instead of Ingress
> Objects as the only way to configure Ingress’ beyond their basic
> routing spec is to use lots of vendor-specific Kubernetes Annotations
> to your Kubernetes manifests.

So you are supposed to use [VirtualService](https://docs.solo.io/gloo/latest/guides/traffic_management/request_processing/timeout/) in order to achieve your goal. You can see the example below:

```
apiVersion: gateway.solo.io/v1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: 'default'
  namespace: 'gloo-system'
spec:
  virtualHost:
    domains:
    - '*'
    routes:
    - matchers:
       - prefix: '/petstore'
      routeAction:
        single:
          upstream:
            name: 'default-petstore-8080'
            namespace: 'gloo-system'
      options:
        timeout: '20s'
        retries:
          retryOn: 'connect-failure'
          numRetries: 3
          perTryTimeout: '5s'
```

I hope this helps.